# Responsive image before and after <h1> tag

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to do something like this: [Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VcKh.png)

The idea is to make the responsive image before and after the H1 tag in CSS. But the only thing I managed is to put a normal line [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22gHG/835/).

```
<h1 ><i class="logo"></i><span>HELLO WORLD</span></h1>

<style>
h1 {
position: relative;
color: #fff;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 4.6rem;
font-weight: 700;
line-height: 4.6rem;
letter-spacing: .02rem;
margin: 0 auto 5rem;
padding: 0 1rem;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
h1 span:before, h1 span:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.73em;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
h1 span:before {
  right: 100%;
}

h1 span:after {
  left: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I managed somehow to get the images before and after the h1 tag, but they aren't responsive [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0m64mdun/2/).

```
<h1 class="heading"><i class="logo"></i>Welcome World</h1>
<style>
h1{
  display: block;
}

h1.heading {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4.6rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 4.6rem;
  letter-spacing: .02rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}
h1.heading:before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 8px 0;
  content: " ";
  text-shadow: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/fcoggcZ.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 87px;
  position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
}
h1.heading:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 8px 0;
  content: " ";
  text-shadow: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/KCzu3hE.png) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 87px;
  position: absolute;
    right: -83rem;
}
</style>
```

Sorry for the code, it's a little messy, i'm still beginner at it.

Comment: Could you please be more specific as to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: As I said, a page "title" that looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/OlV10hU.png and it's responsive. Right now, when I make windows smaller the text goes over the image that's before the h1 tag and the image after the tag says there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just needed to fix the widths of the before and after elements. They were 100% so were taking up the full width of the title.

I also dropped the font-size. You'll have to take care of that with [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) if you want it to grow on larger screens etc.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: #000;
}

h1{
  display: block;
}

h1.heading {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 87px;
  letter-spacing: .02rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

h1.heading:before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 20px 8px 0;
  content: " ";
  text-shadow: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/fcoggcZ.png) no-repeat right center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 87px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
h1.heading:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  content: " ";
  text-shadow: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/KCzu3hE.png) no-repeat left center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 87px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading"><i class="logo"></i>Welcome World</h1>
```

**EDIT**

I get too into these...
A safer bet would be to wrap the text in a span, then drop off your position absolutes. that way you, if space gets too tight - it will go onto another line.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: #000;
}

h1{
  display: block;
}

h1.heading {
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: .02rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

h1.heading:before {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  content: " ";
  text-shadow: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/fcoggcZ.png) no-repeat right center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 87px;
  left: 0;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
h1.heading:after {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  content: " ";
  text-shadow: none;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/KCzu3hE.png) no-repeat left center;
  width: 30%;
  height: 87px;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

h1.heading span {
  width:40%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading"><span>Welcome World</span></h1>
```

Comment: @GouzdniJouza No problem - I just added another bit too it, to stop it ever going over the images. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun, you can also simplify your code with the use of **flexbox**, which is completely compatible with pseudo elements.

The nice thing is that the images position will adjust to the title width, so you could define a max-width to the h1 div & let flexbox handle the rest.

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background: #000;
}

h1{
  display: flex;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .02rem;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  min-height: 87px;
}

h1:before,
h1:after {
  content: " ";
  flex: 1;
}

h1 div {
  padding: 0 20px;
  align-self: center;
}

h1:before {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/fcoggcZ.png) no-repeat right 20px center;
}

h1:after {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/KCzu3hE.png) no-repeat left 20px center;
}
```

```html
<h1><div>Welcome World</div></h1>
<h1><div>Hey</div></h1>
```

Comment: WOW, nice. This is very useful, will definitely memories it. Thanks.